# FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Column Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE old_events
(day STRING, foo STRING, count STRING, internal_id STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (ds string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION '${INPUT}';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE events
(internal_id, foo STRING, count STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (ds string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION '${OUTPUT}';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE events
SELECT e2.internal_id, e2.foo, count(e1.foo)
FROM old_events e2
LEFT OUTER JOIN old_events e1
ON e1.foo = e2.foo
WHERE e1.event = 'event1'
AND e2.event = 'event2'
AND ds = date_sub('${DAY}',1)
GROUP BY e2.internal_id, e2.foo;
```

FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Column ds Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries

I am getting this error, when adding ds variable that fetches current date.
How do i implemented with the above script to work for date partition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add an alias to `ds` in your `WHERE` clause. ex, `ds = date_sub('${DAY}',1)` to `e2.ds = date_sub('${DAY}',1)`.

To clarify your problem a little bit, here is a smaller example which shows the same behavior

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE example
(a INT, b INT)
LOCATION '${OUTPUT}';

SELECT *
FROM example e1
JOIN example e2
  ON e1.a = e2.a
WHERE b = 5;
```

This creates the same error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException Column b Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries
```

The problem is that column `b` exists in both `example` aliased as `e1` and `e2`. You and I might know that if you join `example` on itself on column `a` then `e1.b` is the same as `e2.b` so it should not need an alias, but Hive does not know this so you need to pick one to remove any ambiguity. It doesn't matter here whether `b` is a partition column or not.